How to integrate AdonisJS + Angular in Nx Monorepo
everyone!
I'd like to make a boilerplate ( front + back ), with Angular on the front and AdonisJS on the back, I've created my WorkSpace and added an Angular application (@nx/angular) , I'd like to know how to add an AdonisJS application, knowing that Nx doesn't yet offer this framework for integration
I've already tried several ways but I have problems each time, what's the best way?
Thanks :)

Can you share with us, the things you already tried?

I create workspace, I have add angular project, I have add node, and after i'm lock, I try run 'npm i create-adonis-ts-app' , but in monorepo context, and in node project that not work
